# Regarding glue transformation logic for dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using aws glue for transforming data from dynamodb tables. I am able to fetch the data and do the transformations using pyspark logic. But when I try to write the file into json format, I am getting a invalid json format.[Current format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJCNg.png). Need help in transforming this json file.

Code:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from datetime import date

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark_context = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glue_context = GlueContext(spark_context)

# glue context to start the glue and spark session
#glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

# Acquire data from glue tables using dynamic frame (stage table)
datasource_1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
             database="test",
             table_name="dynamo_edc_test_stage_table")

# Checking current schema
datasource_1.printSchema()

# Acquire data from glue tables using dynamic frame (main table)
datasource_2 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
             database="test",
             table_name="dynamo_edc_test_main_table")

datasource_2.printSchema()

# Convert glue dynamic frames into spark dataframes using toDF() method, since table has to be registered and sql queries can be run
# Register tables for 2 dataframes so that spark.sql can run sql queries
datasource_1.toDF().registerTempTable('edc_test_stage_table')
datasource_2.toDF().registerTempTable('edc_test_main_table')


# 1) Inserts only if new record arrives
# repartition is done to store the record in a single part file and write mode is used to write the data into s3 bucket with json format
final_output_df_1 = spark.sql('select distinct d.resource_id,1 as version_id,d.file_name,d.last_modified_date,d.folder_name,d.Basic,d.Attributes,"Y" as active_ind from edc_test_stage_table d,edc_test_main_table e where d.folder_name!=e.folder_name')
final_output_target_1="s3://testversionsbeacon/test"
final_output_df_1.repartition(1).write.mode("append").json(final_output_target_1)


# 2) Increments/inserts existing record with new modified date
final_output_df_2 = spark.sql('select e.resource_id,e.version_id+1 as version_id,d.file_name,d.last_modified_date,d.folder_name,d.Basic,d.Attributes,"Y" as active_ind from edc_test_stage_table d,edc_test_main_table e where e.active_ind="Y" and d.folder_name=e.folder_name and d.file_name=e.file_name and d.last_modified_date!=e.last_modified_date')
final_output_target_2="s3://testversionsbeacon/test"
final_output_df_2.repartition(1).write.mode("append").json(final_output_target_2)


# 3) Updates old indicator record into 'N'
final_output_df_3 = spark.sql('select e.resource_id,e.version_id,e.file_name,e.last_modified_date,e.folder_name,e.Basic,e.Attributes,"N" as active_ind from edc_test_stage_table d,edc_test_main_table e where e.active_ind="Y" and d.folder_name=e.folder_name and d.file_name=e.file_name and d.last_modified_date!=e.last_modified_date')
final_output_target_3="s3://testversionsbeacon/test"
final_output_df_3.repartition(1).write.mode("append").json(final_output_target_3)
```

Comment: Can you give more details on the error part?

Comment: When I write the data into s3, the json file is not a valid one when i check with json validator. It starts and starts with {} when it is an array of elements[].

Answer (score 0):

Spark json spits the output file as json lines, so you won't get the list of dictionaries instead you'll get \n separated dictionaries where each row represents a record.

You can directly load this in dynamodb. If you really want to get the list of dictionaries you have to manually do it.

Comment: any suggestion on how to load this directly into dynamodb? i dont find any option to write the dataframe directly into dynamodb

Comment: Not the spark dataframe but the json lines created can be transferred to dynamodb using lambda directly. If your data size is huge you can either use python shell in glue and use multiprocess to load in ddb directly or you can use pywren to initialize a fleet of lambda loading files.